# adb push libdvm.so

Tags: android, dalvik

How can I change the system partition size so that I can do something like `adb push libdvm.so' after making changes to the VM? Without changing the partition size (i.e. using the default setting for the emulator), it complains "out of memory".

Answer (score 1):

To make a larger partition for your AVD after having created the AVD you:

Right click your Project --> Run AS --> Run Configurations -->

(make sure your project is selected on the left and the Name at the top.)

Select 'Target' -->

at the bottom you'll see 'Android Emulator Command Line Options:

[image]

Add something like `-partition-size 1024` which would make your AVD partition 1024MB in size.

**That's how you make your partition bigger**, but I feel your 'out of memory' error wont be resolved from that.

Rather, I think you need to simply increase your Java Memory or Heap size:

If you're on Windows, this will help http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-eclipse.html

The gist of it is to include something like `-vmargs -Xms256M -Xmx512M` to your eclipse.ini file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The 'out of memory' error is not related to heap size. It is reported when the '/system' partition is not big enough to accommodate the new libdvm.so. But I will try to see whether "-partition-size 1024" would work.

Comment: Hopefully then. Also, it would be the same from the command line `emulator -partition-size 1024`